# Android: Drawing overlays on pannable canvas detect touch location

Tags: android, overlay, android-canvas

I am working on a legacy android application which uses a custom class (`TouchGallery`) that extends the `Gallery` class to display JPGs as pages in a magazine. On some pages there will be one or more overlays that are touchable (added dynamically), to fire an `Intent` to open a browser with a URL. I have managed to get the overlays drawn over the page, in the overridden `onDraw()` method. However, now my problem is to detect which enrichment overlay was touched.

The pages are scalable (so users can zoom in and out) and also if zoomed in they can pan around the page. The `TouchGallery` class gets touches and I can pass the touch along to my `ScalableImageView` custom class. My problem is to know where the touch on the canvas was so that I can send the correct URL to the browser. As I'm sure you are already aware that `MotionEvent` co-ordinates are based on the screen and not on the canvas.

I managed to get the touches working (to degree) when the image is fully zoomed out. However, once the page is zoomed the touch co-ordinates are no longer near where they need to be. I used the scale value (screenWidth / bitmapWidth = scaleValue) to "transform" my touch co-ordinates to the fully visible image. I don't think that this approach is viable.

The canvas doesn't have touch co-ordinates as it is used for drawing. But I assume that what I want to do is possible, because if you think about some drawing apps, you can zoom in and it will draw the line (or whatever is being drawn) in the correct location.

My view structure is as follows:
`TouchGallery` > `TouchImageview` > `ScalableImageView` > `EnrichmentBlockView`

**More info about custom classes:**

> *TouchGallery*
>
> `TouchGallery extends Gallery implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`
>
> Handles loading the JPG pages

---

> *TouchImageView*
>
> `TouchImageView extends TwoDScrollView implements ScalableView, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`
>
> Handles the gestures (zooming, panning, double-tap)

---

> *ScalableImageView*
>
> `ScalableImageView extends View implements BitmapConsumer, View.OnTouchListener`
>
> Handles displaying the bitmap object and the drawing of `EnrichmentBlockView`

---

> *EnrichmentBlockView*
>
> `EnrichmentBlockView extends View`
>
> Handles the sizing of the overlay and **I would like it to handle the touch of a specific enrichment overlay**.

Would it be possible to `setOnTouchListener()` to dynamically added views? If yes, how would I go about it?

I have tried dynamically adding buttons as the overlays, but when you get more than two buttons being added, the page scaling and panning becomes very sluggish. Would this be the best option, if done correctly? I might have added the views incorrectly which could cause the sluggishness.

tl; dr

I need to detect touch co-ordinates on the canvas as opposed to the touch location on the screen. Either, a way to determine the "view port" or transform touch co-ordinates to canvas co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using `getLocationInWindow()` in the overridden `onTouch()` event and subtracting the x and y values from `motionEvent.getX()` and `motionEvent.getY()` respectively. I then pass those values to my *EnrichmentBlockView* custom class.

Essentially that "transformed" the touch co-ordinates to canvas co-ordinates. Then in the `onDraw()` I check if the `Rect` object contains my "transformed" co-ordinates. If the co-ordinates are in the `Rect`, then the URL is passed to the browser intent that gets fired.

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar problem.